# Why are bugs attracted to light bulbs but not flames?

Tags: entomology

Just now, a housefly was bugging me a lot and I wanted to get rid of it. My mother suggested me to turn off the lightbulb and off it went. However a small flame was burning in my room. Why didn't the housefly get attracted to the flame (although it was a luminous flame)?

My first guess is because of the high temperature a flame produces. [This Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen_lamp) article states that:

> A 300 watt tubular halogen bulb operated at full power quickly reaches a temperature of about 540 °C (1,004 °F)

And a charcoal fire can produce temperatures between 750–1,200 °C (1382-2192 °F). [Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame#Common_flame_temperatures).

I've seen small bugs getting attracted to large halogen lights in sports complexes. Although these two temperature ranges are a sizable difference apart, 540 °C doesn't seem *cool* at all. Is it really due to temperature, or is there some other reason?

Comment: It could be something to do with them learning to avoid flames over many years. Fire is more of a natural occurrence than halogen bulbs. It could biologically coded within them to avoid flames. The same way the average human would run at the sight of a tarantula, but doesn't get hugely scared if they just saw a plastic model of a spider, insects may know innately that fire is harmful, but newer man-made sources of light may not invoke the same biologically-driven behavioral response.

Comment: Not all animals are attracted to light but those that are are motivated by mating behavior. Some female moths will seek a light source and release pheromones drawing the males to the light. The old stories about a moth flying into a flame is a myth

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with temperature, but with the **color of the light**. Insects are especially attracted to lights with short wavelenghts, especially Ultraviolet (UV) light. Yellow and red light attract far less insects. (Rich & Longcore 2006). [PDF](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/40777410_Ecological_Consequences_of_Artificial_Night_Lighting)

White light, like the one emitted by an average light bulb, consists of a broad spectrum, that includes UV. [Halogen lights also emit UV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen_lamp). Flames on the other hand emit mostly red and yellow light.

Unless the flames burn at a very high temperature, then the flames turn blue. To illustrate this, my parents used to have a candlelight on gas they used during camping. This light burnt at a very high temperature, and hence the flame had a bluish color. And it did attract insects, especially moths.